# Unreachable empty list item in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

When I create an ordered list in an contenteditable div element like in the example below I can't access empty list items in Firefox. In Chrome it works in terms of functionality, but there is still a minor indentation issue.

## The Problem

Consider the example below. (also available as [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Scindix/6jkvfn42/)) Here you can see that I create the ordered list using JavaScript. Each line becomes a list item. The second list item is empty because the line is empty. Also I'm using a custom list style.

### CSS

```
#editable ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#editable ol > li {
    counter-increment: customlistcounter;
}
#editable ol > li::before {
    content: counter(customlistcounter) " ";
}
#editable ol:first-child {
    counter-reset: customlistcounter;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="editable" id="editable" contenteditable="true">first

third</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var editable = document.getElementById("editable");
editable.innerHTML = '<ol><li>'+editable.textContent.split("\n").join('</li><li>')+"</li></ol>";
```

## Behaviour

### In Firefox 48.0

If I set the cursor to the end of the first line and move the cursor to the right using the keyboard the cursor immediately jumps to the third line. Likewise if set the cursor to the beginning of the third line and press the left arrow key the cursor jumps to the first line. Also I can't set the cursor to the second line using the mouse.

### In Chromium 52.0

In contrast to Firefox I can set the cursor to the second line with both mouse and keyboard. However the cursor caret appears in front of the item marker instead of behind it. When I type a character the cursor jumps to the right side. It stays on the right side even when I delete that character again.

### Expected behavior

When I copy and use the HTML code that JavaScript generated (e.g. using Firebug), drop the JavaScript part and the custom list style I end up with the following code (also available as [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Scindix/376sdxv7/)):

```
<div class="editable" id="editable" contenteditable="true"><ol><li>first</li><li></li><li>third</li></ol></div>
```

This works in both Firefox and Chrome. You can set the cursor to the second line and the cursor caret is displayed at the right position.
The CSS part has its fair share of the problem. If you do not drop it you can reach the second line via mouse and via arrow keys from the first line, but not from the third line. And you cannot reach the first line from the second via keyboard.

## The Question

Why doesn't it work using the first method? Shouldn't it lead to the exact same behavior? Is it a bug, undefined behavior or am I missing something here?
Also how can I work around this issue? I have to create the content in the contenteditable div element with JavaScript. Also I want to use a custom list style. But I want the behavior from my second example where I'm able to edit the empty second line.

## Update

I thought a second time about it. As the pure HTML/CSS version worked better it might have been a parser issue. So I tried a different approach in creating the list items. Just in case you were curious the following doesn't work either. The behavior is exactly as in my first attempt.

```
var editable = document.getElementById("editable");
var lines = editable.textContent.split("\n");

while(editable.firstChild) {
    editable.removeChild(editable.firstChild);
}
var ol = document.createElement("ol");

for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(lines[i]);
    li.appendChild(textnode);
    ol.appendChild(li)
}
editable.appendChild(ol);
```

Comment: Trying to create your own rich text editor? Tried that once, making the output and behavior the same between browsers is a nightmare il never forget... Maybe it's better now but I'm staying away from contenteditable till I know for sure it's finally the same between browsers.

Comment: @seahorsepip I already got quite far. This is more or less the last issue I have to fix.
But yeah, you're right. contenteditable **is** a nightmare. Not only in case of platform independence. Maybe W3C should've created their own standard instead of using an Internet Explorer extension.

Comment: Upvoted for being an excellently structured question from a "newbie" (based on your rep).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround solution would be to add an invisible character in each empty line. Something like `&zwnj;`.

```
var editable = document.getElementById("editable");
editable.innerHTML = '<ol><li>'+editable.textContent.split("\n").join('</li><li>').split('<li></li>').join('<li>&zwnj;</li>')+"</li></ol>";
```

The downside is that the user has to press the arrow keys two times in some cases as `&zwnj;` is treated as a normal character. If one needs to also fix this one could do this by listening for keypress events and correct the position of the caret manually.